# Display(Name = "") only works on certain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This MVC 5 application came from a database first approach.  Therefore a partial class was added to handle any validation, etc.

For some reason, [Display(Name = "")] will not work on any fields that are a foreign key in the database (have SelectList in the view).  It works for all other fields.  The name this is actually rendered is the the "campaign_id" column in the database on the Create / Edit pages.  On the Index / Details / Delete pages it is "Name" (with a capital N which does not follow any of our naming conventions).

```
public class mailMetadata
     {

         [Required]
         [Display(Name = "Campaign")]
         public int campaign_id;
 }
```

I have also tried the use of DisplayName("") with no success either.

**UPDATED CODE FOR VIEW RENDERING**

Create / Edit

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.campaign_id, "campaign_id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Details / Index / Delete

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.campaign.campaign_id)
```

I am looking for an understanding of why this is happening, as well as help with how to remedy.  There are a bunch of Q/A's on this topic, but none seem to work.

Comment: Include how you are rendering it in the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke updated to include how it is being rendered in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the overload of `@Html.LabelFor()` that has the second parameter as *the label text to display*. [Refer docuemntation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833698(v=vs.118).aspx). Change it to

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.campaign_id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Comment: Wow.  Great, thank you.  Any idea why DisplayNameFor would not be working in the Details / Delete / Index?  They are using DisplayNameFor.

Comment: Should be fine. Are you sure `model => model.campaign.campaign_id` is correct (i.e. your model has a property `campaign` which has property `campaign_id`). If so is `campaign` null? (in which case the fallback would be "campaign_id")

Comment: That was the issue.  It was going to the `campaign` property and there was ambiguity on the names.  Thanks!